# How to use custom drop shadow with blur efftect CardView in android

Tags: android

I need to add custom drop shadow with blur in android CardView . I need the **CardView ** bellow like image

[image]

**I have tried bellow like..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#008EFF33" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

I have tried it in css which is working fine..here is my css code

```
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #008EFF33;
 border-radius: 10px;
 opacity: 1
```

But I could not do above image in android.Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Why not use `CardView` ?

Comment: @ADM I tried to make card view like the image , but I can not set the shadow & blur in card view

Comment: @ADM Can you help me to make the card view above the like image?